# Generalized 7-11 mathematical

Tags: python-2.7, math

I have to write a program that solves the 7-11 problem (if you don't know what this is, Google will explain) but instead of finding the values that add and multiply to make $7.11, I have to find all the unique values of *a, b, c* and *d* that add and multiply to make $*x.yz* between $1.00 and $9.99.

It gets to the if statement where it checks if a, b, c and d multiply to make n but it is never true.

```
def factors(n):
    #Finds all the factors of n and adds them to an array
    factors_of_n = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        if(n % i == 0):
            factors_of_n.append(i)

    #Runs through the array and checks if they add and multiply to
    #equal n
    for a in factors_of_n:
        for b in factors_of_n:
            for c in factors_of_n:
                for d in factors_of_n:
                    if(a < b and b < c and c < d):
                        if(a + b + c + d == n):
                            if(a * b * c * d == n * 1000000):
                                #It never gets into this loop
                                print "please"
                                return True                 
def g711():
    min = 100
    max = 999
    count = 0

    for n in range(min, max):
        if factors(n):
            print "yay"
```

I just need somebody that is a bit better at maths than I am to check it over and see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why do you assume the answers have to be factors of `n`? The solution to `7.11` is '3.16, 1.25, 1.50, 1.20` none of which are factors of `7.11`.

Comment: I figured that it would limit the number of iterations it would have to go through but now that I actually think about it you are right... I feel like an idiot.

Comment: So instead of using the factors of n as constraints, how would I limit the number of iterations that the program runs through? Otherwise it has to run through every permutation from 1 to n, for every number from 100 to 999.

Comment: You may want to consider the factors of `n*1000000 if < n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

def factors(n):
    ...

r = {}
for n in range(100, 999):
    for a, b, c, d in cwr([f for f in factors(n*1000000) if f < n], r=4):
        if a+b+c+d == n and a*b*c*d == n*1000000:
            r.setdefault(n, []).append((a,b,c,d))
```

Results:

```
{644: [(125, 160, 175, 184)],
 651: [(125, 140, 186, 200)],
 660: [(110, 150, 200, 200)],
 ...
 711: [(120, 125, 150, 316)],
 ...
 992: [(32, 250, 310, 400)]
}
```